# Formatting telephone numbers basing on a country

Tags: codenameone

I want to format the telephone numbers to: 1) Start with +country code, 2) Format the numbers (spacing after a given number of figures) depending on the recognized country format. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this tutorial on phone number/country code selection: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-activation-ui-builder-pattern.html

If you want separate fields for each block in the number see this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/validation-regex-masking.html specifically the auto move functionality to "jump" to the next field.